# echo variable variable name

Tags: php, variables, variable-variables

I want to echo a variable variable name, this doesn't work:

```
echo ($["IMG$i"]);
```

`$i` is `1` in this case, and it changes while the for loop goes on.

`$IMG1` is an variable with a value

Comment: use array this suits well your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you can do this.

```
$variablename = 'IMG' . $i;
echo $$variablename;
```

or simply

```
echo ${IMG . $i};
```

This is a PHP language feature called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

***This is a really bad idea. Do not do it.***

Instead, build an array.

```
$images = array('first', 'second', 'third');
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo $image;
}

// or

for ($i = 0; i < count($images); $i++) { // this might be what you already have
    echo $images[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains syntax errors, but assuming you have a variable `$arr` that is your array, all you need to do is `echo $arr["IMG" . $i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $arr['IMG' . $i];
```

Simple as pie. I don't recommend string interpolation (using variables inside double-quotes) because of it's poor performance and security vulnerabilities.